# onCreateOptionsMenu is not doing anything for me

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I'm totally stuck why this is happening. The options menu was working just fine, but now it's no longer working.

When I hit the menu button, the menu opens, I tap it and nothing. It does register the MenuItem when I do my LogCat... I'm seriously going to pull my hair, I don't understand why this is happening.

> 06-06 22:19:07.899:
>   DEBUG/MYTAG(23124): Stupid clicker
>   id=save settings item id=2133000192
>   id2=2133065728

Below is the code and xml

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Clicked saved1");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Stupid clicker id="+item+" item id="+item.getItemId()+" id2="+R.mainmenuSettings.save1);
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.mainmenuSettings.save1:
            Log.d("MYTAG", "Stupid clicker");
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:id="@+mainmenuSettings/save1"
            android:title="save settings"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Is this activity a subactivity of tabhost...?

Comment: For effing sakes!! I deleted the old settings.xml and made a new one but with a different name "mysettings.xml" I even changed the id to mysettings. Now it works! I tried this already in the old XML file, but with no results...I just want to know WHY!?

Comment: @Dinesh, neither(I think) It's all in one activity/class. Please bare with me, I've been learning java and android for about two months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an error in your menu XML. The "id" attribute needs to start with "@+id/", so this needs to be "@+id/mainmenuSettingsSave1" or something similar. Also, you'll need to reference this in your code as R.id.mainmenuSettingsSave1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mainmenuSettingsSave1"
          android:title="save settings"/>
</menu>
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Clicked saved1");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Stupid clicker id="+item+" item id="+item.getItemId()+" id2="+R.id.mainmenuSettingsSave1);
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.mainmenuSettingsSave1:
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Stupid clicker");
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: really? I've been using @+anyname/label in many test programs and that worked fine...

Comment: If you don't use the correct prefix, then Android will not recognise it as an ID resource. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id if you don't believe me.